# Selenium - How to find color of a pixel on canvas on X Y position?

Tags: python, selenium, canvas, colors

I'm using selenium with python and I have a problem: I want to get pixel color of x y position on canvas.

Does Selenium have some color picker or something similar?

I tried get color of a pixel with getCssValue but it doesn't work because it is canvas.

This is an example what I'm trying to achieve

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
chrome_options = Options()

prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values': {'images': 1,
                            'plugins': 2, 'geolocation': 2,
                            'notifications': 2, 'auto_select_certificate': 2, 'fullscreen': 2,
                            'mouselock': 2, 'mixed_script': 2, 'media_stream': 2,
                            'media_stream_mic': 2, 'media_stream_camera': 2, 'protocol_handlers': 2,
                            'ppapi_broker': 2, 'automatic_downloads': 2, 'midi_sysex': 2,
                            'push_messaging': 2, 'ssl_cert_decisions': 2, 'metro_switch_to_desktop': 2,
                            'protected_media_identifier': 2, 'app_banner': 2, 'site_engagement': 2,
                            'durable_storage': 2}}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"C:\gecko\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://drawisland.com/")

act = ActionChains(driver)
canvas = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("canvas")
act.move_to_element_with_offset(canvas,100,100).GetColor().perform()
```

Comment: Upvoted your question. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently not possible directly with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly get the color of a pixel because you need an element to request the color.

Python Background Color Snippet

```
background_colour = element.value_of_css_property('background-color'))
```

What you could do is creating an screenshot from an element or the full page and then use maybe a other libary like ImageMagick to validate the image.

Since Selenium 4.0 there is a limited support for working with [colors](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/additional_features/colors/).